# Why does Selenium WebDrivers always open addon "Welcome" page when running the driver?

Tags: python-2.7, firefox, selenium, firefox-addon

Ok this started happening to me today when running my script. I have been working on a refreshing program that opens several pages and refreshes them randomly on python. Recently I updated firefox and updated my browser (addons, themes, etc.), I think this update may be the cause to my problem but it happened before as well but only with the firefox welcome page. I basically want to make a script specific WebDriver profile(w/ Selenium) that doesn't have any one my normal browser addons or cookies. (a default Firefox webdriver)

I have reset the browsers plugin and settings and this didn't work. It only reset the preferences for my main browser. I also reinstalled selenium and this didn't change a thing. I've looked everywhere for maybe a line of code to disable plugins on firefox, but haven't had any luck. I hope somebody has an answer this is very annoying! Feel free to ask me for left out info.

- python 2.7
- selenium 2.48

Comment: I don't see any problems here...

Comment: my problem is that before this crap, selenium used to open a default browser with no addons and now it does and opens their welcome pages. I dont want that. I want addons disabled and no add welcome pages.

Also when I add a profile my whole program seems to bug out when running the .get('url') line more than once and gives me some error "can't find profile".

Comment: @ViolentJimmy, did you ever figure out a solution for this?